# Access Pythons predefined array names via function parameters

Tags: python, arrays, function, parameters, arguments

I have filled arrays in my code, and I want to acces to it by calling its names in function parameters.
**I was not very accurate**, I need to *access the arrays names*, *and the values too*. I just paste the whole code to you, maybe I missed something:

```
#the path of the dictionary txt files
dictionarypath = 'C:\\src\\'
#example files: qone.txt, adj.txt, subj.txt, gly.txt


#fill "dictionary-file-named" arrays to the words
dictnum=0
dictionaryfiles = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(dictionarypath):
    for file in f:
        if '.txt' in file:   
            dictname=(file[0:-4])
            dictionaryfiles.append(dictname)

            #getting the word from the files and put them into the named arrays (ex.: from subject.txt to subj[])
            dictfile = dictionarypath + dictionaryfiles[dictnum] + '.txt'

            with codecs.open(dictfile, encoding='latin1') as fp:

                line = fp.readline()
                vars()[dictname]=[] #set the actual array to empty first
                while line:
                    vars()[dictname].append(line.strip())
                    line = fp.readline()
            dictnum=dictnum+1   

#this generate the random sentence
def rstc(*pos): 
        for x in range(len(pos)):            
            actdictname=(pos[x])
            if len(actdictname) > 0:
                gennum=random.randrange(0, len(actdictname), 1)                
                sys.stdout.write(actdictname[gennum]+" ")

#qone -> question word (what)
#adj  -> adjectives
#subj -> subjects
#gly  -> glyps (!,.)

rstc(qone,adj,subj,subj,gly)
```

Comment: what[1][2] is Judo, right ?

Comment: What happens when you run the first snippet?

Comment: No it is not a homework or anything, I just want to put my bash script to python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thought of what you are looking is:

```
cars = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"]
sports= ["Football", "Basketball", "Judo"]

def myFunc(what):
    print(eval(what[0])[0])# ->> prints out "Ford"
    print(eval(what[1])[1])# ->> prints out "Basketball"

myFunc(["cars", "sports"])
```

Or

```
def myFunc(what):
    print(what[0][0])# ->> prints out "Ford"
    print(what[1][1])# ->> prints out "Basketball"

myFunc(cars, sports)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the function with `myFunc(cars, sports)` should work just fine. Otherwise, the code seems to work.

Comment: Not with the double indexing though, than it would just two one dimensional lists

Comment: Sorry my bad overlooked the asterix

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just pass both arrays in as seperate arguments and use them inside the function:

```
def myFunc(cars, sports):
    print(cars[0]) # ->> prints out "Ford"
    print(sports[1]) # ->> prints out Basketball

myFunc(cars, sports)
```

If they have to be grouped as a single function argument that can be done like so:

```
def myFunc(stacked_list):
   print(stacked_list[0][0]) # ->> prints out "Ford"
   print(stacked_list[1][1]) # ->> prints out Basketball

myFunc([cars, sports])
```

Comment: I just corrected the question with the full code, because I was not too accurate at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a list of lists and choose the list with I and its element with j:

```
cars = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"]
sports= ["Football", "Basketball", "Judo"]

def myFunc(what, i, j):
    print(what[i][j])

myFunc([cars, sports], 0, 0) # ->> prints out "Ford"
myFunc([cars, sports], 1, 1) # ->> prints out "Basketball"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, actually it works now:

```
            actdictname=pos[x] 
            actdictval=eval(pos[x])[0] 
            actdictlen=len(eval(pos[x]))
```

I can reach the functions parameter, the arrays name, and other parameters, thanks!